# how to create a javascript Set with objects?

Tags: javascript

I have a json file `businessList.json` with the following

```
[
{"availableTimes": [{"type": "time", "time": "06:30"}, {"type": "time", "time": "07:00"}]},

{"availableTimes": [{"type": "time", "time": "08:30"}, {"type": "time", "time": "07:00"}]}
]
```

In another file, I am trying to create a set out of this, but it won't work, it'll show all of the duplicate values. I'm assuming it's because of how objects are passed by reference. How could I solve this to get to the desired result?

```
const timesAvailable = new Set()
businessList.map(item => item.availableTimes.map(item => timesAvailable.add(item))) //won't work
```

Comment: No object is equal to any other object. The properties and property values don't figure into comparison. Two objects that *look* identical are distinct as far as the language and in particular the Set mechanism is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

Like the first comment by Pointy says, objects are only equal to each other in JavaScript if they refer to the same place in memory. For example,

```
const object1 = { foo: 'bar' };
const object2 = object1;

object1 === object2 //true;
{ foo: 'bar' } === { foo: 'bar' } //false
```

There isn't any way around it with `Set`. One thing I've done in a similar situation is loop through the array and create a dictionary (either with a JavaScript `Object` or `Map`), generating a unique key for each item, then iterating through that `Object` or `Map` to get the unique times.

For example, in your case, something like:

```
const availableTimesMap = availableTimes.reduce((acc, timeObject) => {
  const key = `${timeObject.type}-${timeObject.time}`;
  acc[key] = timeObject;
}, {});

const uniqueTimes = Object.values(availableTimesMap);
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my own project. To solve it I ended up having to use strings to be the keys of a Map object. You would need to figure out a standard way to ID a time so that two "identical" times are converted to identical strings. Simply using the time would probably work well enough.

```js
const timesAvailable = new Map()
businessList.forEach(item =>
    item.availableTimes.forEach(item =>
        timesAvailable.add(item.time, item)
    )
)
```

Alternatively, you could do away with objects and just use the string times.

```
[
    {"availableTimes": ["06:30", "07:00"]},
    {"availableTimes": ["08:30", "07:00"]}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the structure of the result you want to get. I assume that if you want to get a set of non-duplicate objects and each object looks like this: {"type": "time", "time": "06:30"}.

```
let businessList = [
    {"availableTimes": [{"type": "time", "time": "06:30"}, {"type": "time", "time": "07:00"}]},

    {"availableTimes": [{"type": "time", "time": "08:30"}, {"type": "time", "time": "07:00"}]}
]
const timesAvailable = new Set(); // a set of strings representing time, which is used for checking duplicates
const availableBusiness = new Set(); //the result we want 

for(let business of businessList) {
    for (let availableTime of business.availableTimes) {
        if(availableTime.type === "time") {
            if(!timesAvailable.has(availableTime.time)){
                timesAvailable.add(availableTime.time);
                availableBusiness.add(availableTime);
            } 
        }
    }
}
console.log(availableBusiness);
console.log(timesAvailable);
```